# Ignite SQL tool query for collections within object

Tags: caching, ignite, dbeaver

I am using Ignite v2.1 and dbeaver to query caches. Is it possible to query collections within a objects in the cache, or complex object within object in the cache? And if so, what it the syntax?

For example, if I have a cache such as IgniteCache and Person looked like the following, what would the syntax be to 1) select the address and 2) select the siblings names & addresses?

```
class Person {
  String name;
  Addresss address;
  Collection<Person> siblings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do SQL over nested collections in Ignite: SQL standard does not support such things. SQL tables are flat.

Think regular SQL databases: you need to introduce `Person.id` and `Person.parentId` (for one-to-many), or a separate mapping table (for many-to-many), then use SQL `JOIN` to query siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare [QueryEntity](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes) for this cache, with list of fields and indexes on this cache, then you can use its fields in SQL queries. Annotations driven setup is explained in the same doc, pick one which suits you better.

Then the 1) will probably be something like `SELECT ADDRESS FROM PERSONCACHE.PERSON WHERE NAME = ?`.

Foreign keys are not supported, however, and I'm don't think that `siblings` setup will work. It doesn't work like that for relational databases unless you add join tables. Ignite is not a graph database.